# How to create such custom button?

Tags: android, button, android-custom-view

How can I create a Button with a custom touch area?
I want to create curved Buttons like the ones below:

[image]

But only the area under the curve should be clickable, so simple ImageButtons won't work since the hitbox is rectangular.

1pic. how it works with ImageButtons
2pic. one of the versions as have to be

[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Can you clearify?

Comment: @Gumbo I've got such panel http://i.stack.imgur.com/cnbkd.png 
How can I make buttoms like these? I have every button .png but i can't cleary understand how to realize them.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein If I put them like rectangular view there will be problem with rise\call button, it will be under FoldView and CheckView like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cowi.png
But I think, that better will be like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/kHFVE.png

Maby I can do Invisible Canvases of triangle and ellipse, and after just put them above my pictures? Somthing like that, Im just new in Android dev.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein how can i disign it?

Comment: @Shagi. I believe you have a good issue to ask about, and is something I've struggled with in the past. But your question is not very clear, so it will not get good answers.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein sorry, but i still can't understand how to prevent superposition and why 4 views? im realy bad at this :( it's just my first project for myself. maby u can show me sample?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein now it's open again... don't know how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved that porblem by one ImageView and onTouchListener. I've calculated the formula for each button-zone and cross-checked the coordinates of touching view.
Here the code for Check and Fold buttons:

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // нажатие
            if (y > 0.98 * x +75) {
                Log.d("TEST", x+" __FOLD__ "+y);
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fold_all);
            } else
            if(y > -0.98 * (x-1200)){
                Log.d("TEST", x+" __CHECK__ "+y);
                img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_all);
            } else {
                Log.d("TEST", x+" __NOTHING__ "+y);
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // движение
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // отпускание
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.all);
            break;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Views are **rectangular**, by nature.

So, simply put a background image in the container Layout and lay your (transparent) ImageViews or TextViews (without any image or text inside) over it.
And react to their click listener/s.

This is the basic idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rise_call_bg"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtLeft"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMidLeft"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMidRite"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRite"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Which results in something like this:

[image]

Each TextView is clickable.
So, just add the click listener/s (a centralized one or individual ones - you choose), and it's done.

---

The user will think the Buttons are what s/he sees: the drawn text underneath the TextViews.

---

Note: I selected all the TextViews, only to make them visible at design time.
They'll be completely transparent at runtime.

You may want to rise the height a bit, say up to 120dp.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, i will use it for a while, but if I want to show that button is pressed, i'll need change full background?

Comment: With **this** solution, yes (OR simply add a colored, semitransparent,  background to the hit TextView - possibly, by using a StateList drawable)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this solution.
The core idea is to detect whether touch in bitmap or not.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22325218/1979882

Comment: an interesting solution, but do we not get the bitmap from the ImageView (Image Button) which has rectangular frame?